# When computing the CDF from a PDF, why is the integral bound a different variable? $F(x) =\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)\,dt$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Right now, I know the variable in the integral must be x, otherwise, the final result does not match the published CDFs of popular distributions. But I don't know why conceptually this is. If the CDF is just the area under the pdf, why isn't it a simple integral, with the same variable t?

$$ \eqalign{
F(x) =P[X\le x]&=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)\,dt\cr
&=\int_0^x \lambda e^{-\lambda t}\,dt\cr
&= -e^{-\lambda t}\,\bigl|_0^x \cr
&=-e^{-\lambda x}-(-e^0)\cr
&=1-e^{-\lambda x}.
}$$

The above is an example of how to get the CDF of the exponential distribution. While pdf is f(t), the integral uses x as a bound. Why?

Answer (score 4):

$x$ is the dependent variable of $F$ and $t$ is just a dummy variable for the integration.

In principle there's nothing wrong with replacing $t$ by $x$, but then you've assigned $x$ two meanings.

In general, if $F$ is defined as an integral of $f$, then we write
$$F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(t)\;dt$$
instead of
$$F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(x)\;dx$$
to make precise that $x$ is the dependent variable and $t$ is just a dummy variable that is "integrated out," though no one will mistake what you mean in either.

Comment: so is it ok to say that the reason that it's okay to use f(t) and F(x) is because F(x)'s "x" is completely separate from f(t)'s "t"? I guess the reason I'm confused is because the variable time is always the same, lets say in physics, when you go from acceleration, to velocity, to distance.

Comment: The properties of a function remain the same whether you use $t,x,y,\alpha,u,etc.$ as the name for the dependent variable.  It is strictly a matter of choice/convenience and to keep things clear for the exposition.  $t$ in this case has nothing to do with time.